# How can I make the user create/input a new book data (Using OOP)

Tags: c++, class, oop

A book in the library has some data which are: book title, book number, copy number (assuming that there may be more than one copy of the same book), publishing year and whether this book is borrowed or not. Assume there are maximum 10 books in the library. The user should be able to "create" a new book and input/modify its data. The user should be able to get a report on all books in the library, the number of borrowed books and the number of books that were published in a certain year. (Note: You must add other data items as needed to complete this task) **I should create at least 2 classes, How can I make the user create/input a new book data (Using OOP)**
**PS: I'm not sure about the code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class book
{
    private:
    string title[10];
    int bookno[10];
    int copyno[20];
    int year[10];
    book () // constructor
    {
        booktitle = "";
        bookno = 0;
        copyno = 0;
        publishyear = 0;
    }
    public:
    void setTitle (string t) // setter
    {
        title = t;
    }
    string getTitle () // getter
    {
        return title;
    }
    void setBookno (int n) // setter
    {
        bookno = n;
    }
    int getBookno () // getter
    {
        return bookno;
    }
    void setCopyno (int c) // setter
    {
        copyno = c;
    }
    int getCopyno () // getter
    {
        return copyno;
    }
    void setYear (int y) // setter
    {
        year = y;
    }
    int getYear () //getter
    {
        return year;
    }

    void creat_book()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=01;i++)
        {

        cout <<"Name of the book"<<title[]<<endl;
        cout <<"Book number is:"<<bookno[]<<endl;
        cout <<"published year is:"<<year[]<,endl;

        }
    }
int main()
{
    book b1;
    b1.get_booktitle ();
    b1.get_bookno ();
    b1.get_copyno ();
    b1.get_borrowed ();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The other noun in your problem description is "library", which should hold "maximum 10 books". See if your textbook mentions something about `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, your `book` class should contain information about just one book. You seem to have allocated space for all 10 books (eg you have `string title[10]` instead of `string title`)

Comment: It won't compile, so that's probably the first thing to consider regarding whether it's feasible thus far. Pretty sure the intended plan from the instruction is your two classes to be `Book` (holds information about **a** book), and `Library` (the latter being a container holding as many as ten of the former).

Comment: Your current code won't even compile. Did you ever even try to run this? For example your book constructor is private it's currently not possible to create instances of your book class.

Comment: It appears your assignment is trying to teach you about Data Modeling. A technique used to designing classes in OOP. The goal in Data Modeling is to separate data into classes so as to reduce redundancy and make it easier to manage, perform analysis on, and store and access that data. To me, it appears that a Library would need to keep two types of records in their system. One for each title they have (author, year...) and one for each physical book in the library (is it checked out and by who). They probably also need a record to know who each of there members are but that's outside the scope